# How to localize a robot in a known map

Tags: navigation, mapping, fake-localization, amcl, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm new in this world of mobile robots and ROS. Currently I wanna know if there are techniques implemented in ROS for self-localization or localization of a robot in a known map that it's provided by a map_server.
I try to use AMCL from de Navigation Stack but I could not make it work because I use hector_mapping without odometry information to build a accurate map and, in this moment, my robot doesn't  provide me the odometry information.
I just wanna know if anyone in this community has/meets or has developed a technique ir ros to do this requirement for navigating.
I configured my amcl.launch like several examples in this community but AMCL doesn't work. I tried this solution (http://answers.ros.org/question/104971/using-hector-slam-with-amcl-for-localization-in-a-pre-made-map/)  and unfortunately I could not get good results, in RVIZ the particleCloud topic doesn't provide a real good localization, any error or warning doesn't appear in the console and all particles, provide  in this topic, diverge against to converge to a good pose. I don't know what to do. I think I have to provide a good odometry from my robot but I have read that if I  provide bad odometry, AMCL won't work. Anyone knows or has a good tutorial to do that, the information from AMCL package is still insufficient for me because I'm  a noob in these topics.

Please, help me, I would appreciate any idea, comment  or any solution to do this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194102/how-to-localize-a-robot-in-a-known-map/) by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-03**:
how are you driving your robot ? if you  have velocities you can [publish odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom)

**Comment by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on 2014-10-03**:
I drive my robot with a  PWM's modulation (I send a PWM reference), so I can't  really estimate the velocities of my robot because my driver control (Driver Maxon Exon 50) doesn't provide me the information about my sensors, it implements a closed loop control but it doesn't provide me a feedback.

**Comment by [sajal](https://answers.ros.org/users/41875/sajal/) on 2019-06-14**:
@ingcavh I'm having the exact same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

You can use a particle filter to localize a robot. For instance see my [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/bfl/Tutorials/Example%20of%20using%20a%20particle%20filter%20for%20localization%20by%20bfl%20library)

Best Regards,
Alex

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1